# Задачка по WinForms

Tags: winforms, c++

Я делаю программу в c++ (Windows Forms). И мне нужно ввести ряд чисел, например,

```
int x = textBox1->text;
```

Но мне выдает ошибку.

Comment: @Noob Поясните вопрос, в данный момент ничего непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас свойство text; совсем не числового типа, а текстового. Посмотрите как можно перевести тестовый тип в целочисленный (int)

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = Parce.ToInt ( textBox1->text);
```

Что-то такое, как точно парсом пользоваться, не помню. )

Answer (score 1):

Если вы программируете в C#, тогда вам нужен

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.text);
```

а если C++, то

```
int x = Int32::Parse(textBox1->text);
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 и Int32.Parse заложены во фреймворк и доступны как для C#, так и для C++.